# One producer and one consumer vs inconsistent shared resource state

Tags: algorithms, concurrency, parallelism, parallel-programming

I was reading about implementation of producer-consumer problem with one producer and one consumer. Looking at this [paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores) I see the implementation where shared resource access is not synchronized and producer and consumer can modify shared resource leading to its inconsistent state.

```
semaphore fillCount = 0; // items produced
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE; // remaining space

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
        putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount);
        item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

But the following description says:

> The solution above works fine when there is only one producer and consumer.

But when `emptyCount` and `fillCount` are let's say 5 (buffer size is 10), then producer and consumer will simultaneously get access to shared resource and modify underlying collection so for me the solution above does not work fine even if there is only one producer and consumer. Is it the right assumption and a quoted description is wrong?

Comment: It would work if the buffer were implemented as a ring buffer with separate head and tail pointers. You left out the description of how the semaphores cause the producer or consumer to sleep.

Comment: You didn't read far enough https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semantics_and_implementation says: "If the implementation does not ensure atomicity of the increment, decrement and comparison operations, then there is a risk of increments or decrements being forgotten, or of the semaphore value becoming negative. Atomicity may be achieved by using a machine instruction that is able to read, modify and write the semaphore in a single operation..."

Comment: @msw I upvoted your comment, but then I realized that I shouldn't do it, but now I can't undo that. Your quoted part is about incrementing semaphore counter, not about what I am asking about. I am asking about modifying shared data in functions: `putItemIntoBuffer(item)`, `item = removeItemFromBuffer()` Your comment is about `down` and `up` operations and it's clear that they have to be atomic and I am not asking about `up` and `down`, but about `putItemIntoBuffer(item)`, `item = removeItemFromBuffer();`.

Comment: @kdgregory That article describes generic solution so when something is dependant on implementation then that information should be contained in that description. So when something depends on implementation then tath description should not say `The solution above works fine when there is only one producer and consumer.` without providing any additional info about implementation requirements.

Comment: You are using a `semaphore` type in your code. Semaphores require specific atomicity properties and if they don't obtain then *anything* which uses them are not properly guarded by the semaphore. Down must block access atomically to the next operation.

Comment: @msw Its' code from wikipedia. But in that code shared data is protected by two semaphores, not by one, so it is possible for producer and consumer to take actions on shared data at the same moment (of course with atomic semaphores). Producer gets access with `emptyCount` semaphore and at the same moment consument can get access to shared data with `fillCount` semaphore. There is no mutex/binary semaphore protecting shared data from mutual access.

Comment: It's Wikipedia, edit it if you feel there's not enough information. I will note, however, that the top of the article describes the buffer as being a queue, which implies separate read and write pointers.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks: Given that the underlying collection is a shared resource,
won't the producer and consumer threads be able to simultaneously
access and modify the (shared) collection?
Is this the right assumption and is the quoted description therefore wrong?

Your observation is correct--that nothing in the code for producer and consumer
will prevent simultaneous access to the buffer.  Note however that this code
does not define or reference or even mention what the 'buffer' looks like.
That was done on purpose--and is part of the 'goodness' of this solution.

This code is only concerned with synchronizing execution with the two cases
full and empty.  It doesn't matter what kind of structure is used for
buffering (i.e. storing) the items produced while they wait to be consumed.
This code will ensure that the producer only runs if there is room to store another item, and the consumer will only run if there is at least one item stored.

So the description is correct, this code works (for synchronization)
as long as there is only one producer and one consumer.

There is an assumption made that the code for accessing the buffer
will ensure that no conflict occurs--and this assumption is
reasonable because the two threads will not ever need to access the same
locations at the same time.  Producer will only write to an unused space,
and Consumer will only read a space after something is stored there.

The buffer *is* shared--but this code ensures that individual slots
or their indices or pointers are not shared--not for the purpose of synchronization.
So if you can store into and remove from the buffer without conflicts,
then you're fine, no matter how you do it.

[So yes, you were right--BIG RED FLAG--the sharing needs to be addressed.
But we're sure you can solve that part separately.  So you don't actually
need to worry about that here].